# Updating a Cuda 4.0 project to Cuda 4.2

Tags: cuda

I have a VS2010 project that was tested with CUDA 4.0, today I installed CUDA 4.2 and I want to update this project, the problem is that when I try to run the project it asks me for cudart32_40_17.dll, but since this is CUDA 4.2 I only have on my folders (C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\bin) cudart32_42_9.dll. I already set the Build Customizations to Cuda 4.2 and it compiles without any problem, the only problem is when I try to run it, the app asks me for the previous version of the dll. Is there a way to especify that the project must use cudart32_42_9.dll?

Answer (score 1):

There was another library in the project that was compiled using Cuda 4.0, so I have to recompile the library (OpenCV) with Cuda 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

one way, you can use nvidia parallel nsight to change it.
another is reset cuda linker point to the CUDA4.2 ,compiler use 4.2 nvcc.
good luck